# C++ fstream not displaying contenst written in

Tags: c++

[EDITED]
After i write the contents into the file it doesn't display the text its just ends the program. Am i not using fstream correctly?

```
fstream myfile;
int count = 0;

myfile.open("A3Problem2b.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);
if (!myfile.is_open())
{
    cout << "Cannot open file - A3Problem2b.txt"<< endl;
    exit(1);
}

char prompt[1000];

cout << "Enter a line of text with no punctuation <^Z to stop>:\n";
cin.getline(prompt, 1000);
while ( !cin.eof() )
{
    myfile << prompt << endl;
    cin.getline(prompt, 1000);
}

myfile.getline(prompt, 1000);
while ( !myfile.eof() )
{
    cout << prompt << "\n";
    myfile.getline(prompt, 1000);
}
myfile.close();
```

Comment: Where is the file placed relative to your programs working directory (that's not necessarily the same one, as where your source file resides)?

Comment: the file doesnt exist i want to create it aswell

Comment: You exit your program, before giving it the chance, to create the file?

Comment: i added ios::trunc and it works but it is not displaying the text after i write into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rewind the stream before you read from it - `fstream.seekg(0)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::fstream myfile;
    int count = 0;

    myfile.open("kb.nt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    if (!myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file - kb.nt"<< std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    char prompt[1000];

    std::cout << "Enter a line of text with no punctuation <^Z to stop>:\n";

    while ( std::cin.getline(prompt, 1000) )
    {
        myfile << prompt << std::endl;
    }

    myfile.flush();
    myfile.seekg(0);

    while ( myfile.getline(prompt, 1000) )
    {
        std::cout << prompt << "\n";
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```